# StartAnimation on ImageView not called in AlertDialog

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-alertdialog

I have a problem on StartAnimation method. When I'm trying to start animation on ImageView in AlertDialog.Builder (with a layout inflate), the animation starts correctly, but after the first "frame" it  not continue his cicle.
This is my code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(layout);


    ImageView img = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgLoadingDialog);
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake_animation);
    img.startAnimation(shake);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(layout);
```

This is my animation.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="100"
   android:fromDegrees="-20"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"
   android:toDegrees="20" />
```

Comment: I understand now that my problem is caused by another operation, which executed on the mainThread and lock my animation. I resolved when I execute this operation in another separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `DialogFragment`, you will have to override `onCreateDialog` instead of `onCreateView` as follows:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        builder.setView(layout);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
        img.startAnimation(anim);
        return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Check out my new answer. It works for me without any issues

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to display the DialogFragment during a onPreExecute() into an AsyncTask, what i need to do? Thanks

Comment: Create a new instance of the fragment and call show() on it as follows
new MyDialogFrag().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "key")

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I understand now that my problem is caused by another operation, which executed on the mainThread and lock my animation. I resolved when I execute this operation in another separate thread.